# Apache Superset LDAP login failed with 'HTTP 302'

Tags: python, authentication, ldap, openldap, apache-superset

I'm trying to configure Apache Superset with LDAP authentication, but when I click the login button I get a `HTTP 302` error. I can ping the LDAP server in the Docker console, so I can reach the endpoint.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM apache/superset:2.1.0
USER root
ENV ADMIN_USERNAME $ADMIN_USERNAME
ENV ADMIN_EMAIL $ADMIN_EMAIL
ENV ADMIN_PASSWORD $ADMIN_PASSWORD

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping

COPY ./superset-init.sh /superset-init.sh
COPY superset_config.py /app/

ENV SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH /app/superset_config.py

USER superset
ENTRYPOINT [ "/superset-init.sh" ]
EXPOSE 8088:8088
EXPOSE 389:389
```

My `superset_config.py`

```py
import logging
import os
import sys
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP

from superset.jinja_context import (  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    BaseTemplateProcessor,
)
from superset.stats_logger import DummyStatsLogger
from superset.utils.core import is_test
from superset.utils.log import DBEventLogger
from superset.utils.logging_configurator import DefaultLoggingConfigurator

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PROTOCOL = "https"
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PORT = 8088
SUPERSET_WORKERS = 1

SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT = 60

SUPERSET_DASHBOARD_PERIODICAL_REFRESH_LIMIT = 0
SUPERSET_DASHBOARD_PERIODICAL_REFRESH_WARNING_MESSAGE = None

SUPERSET_DASHBOARD_POSITION_DATA_LIMIT = 65535
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = None
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

SECRET_KEY = "KEY_VALUE"
QUERY_SEARCH_LIMIT = 1000

# Flask-WTF flag for CSRF
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED =False 
FLASK_USE_RELOAD = True

SHOW_STACKTRACE = True
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = False
PROXY_FIX_CONFIG = {"x_for": 1, "x_proto": 1, "x_host": 1, "x_port": 1, "x_prefix": 1}

APP_NAME = "Superset"

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = False  # allow users who are not already in the FAB DB
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "AUTH_LDAP_SERVER"
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "cn=CN,ou=OU,ou=OU OM, ou=OU USERS,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XX"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = USER
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = PASSWORD
#AUTH_LDAP_EMAIL_FIELD = ""
#AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED = True 

#PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = 1800

BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE = "en"
BABEL_DEFAULT_FOLDER = "superset/translations"
LANGUAGES = {
    "en": {"flag": "us", "name": "English"},
    "es": {"flag": "es", "name": "Spanish"}
}
LANGUAGES = {}
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: super_admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: SomeSecretPassword
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres-db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  superset:
      build:
        context: ./superset
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: superset
      environment:
        - ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
        - ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
        - ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      ports:
        - '8088:8088'
volumes:
  postgres-db:
    driver: local
```

This is my actual output in the console

```
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:11:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 223 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset  | /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/interface.py:67: SAWarning: relationship 'SqlaTable.slices' will copy column tables.id to column slices.datasource_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Slice.table' (copies tables.id to slices.datasource_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="table"' to the 'SqlaTable.slices' relationship. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/qzyx)
superset  |   for prop in class_mapper(obj).iterate_properties:
superset  | 2023-09-15 18:11:46,116:WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:11:46 +0000] "GET /superset/welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 302 201 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:11:54 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:11:56 +0000] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25240 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:12:25 +0000] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 219 "http://localhost:8088/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset  | 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:12:26 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:12:27 +0000] "GET /login/?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 25325 "http://localhost:8088/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:12:28 +0000] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 219 "http://localhost:8088/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
superset  | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023:18:12:29 +0000] "GET /login/?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 25378 "http://localhost:8088/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```